# Get base class subobject with same cv-qualification and value category as derived class expression

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a type `V` derived from some `std::variant` specialization. The `std::visit` function won't work with a `V` argument so it is necessary to cast to base. For example, instead of

```
std::visit(visitor, std::move(v));
```

it is necessary to write

```
std::visit(visitor, static_cast<V::variant&&>(v));
```

Suppose I'd like to write an overload of `visit` that does the right thing, to avoid having to type out `static_cast` every time I want to visit a `V` object:

```
template <class Visitor, class T,
          class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Val>, Value>>>
auto visit(Visitor&& vis, T&& v) {
    return std::visit(std::forward<Visitor>(vis), ?)
}
```

For the argument `?` I'd like to extract the `variant` base class subobject of `v`, but the resulting expression needs to have the same cv-qualification and value category, or to put it another way, I'd like to perfectly forward the base class subobject. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I’m fairly sure it isn’t legal to overload anything in `std`. Did you actually mean overload, or do you plan to put it in a different namespace?

Comment: @DanielH I meant it would be in a different namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any built-in way to do this. However, it is quite simple to write a set of templates to transfer these qualifiers from one type to another.  For example, `transfer_cv` could be implemented like this:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
struct transfer_const {using type = typename std::remove_const<T2>::type;};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct transfer_const<const T1, T2> {using type = const T2;};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct transfer_volatile {using type = typename std::remove_volatile<T2>::type;};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct transfer_volatile<volatile T1, T2> {using type = volatile T2;};

template<class T1, class T2>
struct transfer_cv {using type = typename transfer_volatile<T1, typename transfer_const<T1, T2>::type>::type;};
```

A template to transfer the value type could be implemented in the same way. You could then simply transfer the qualifiers of your derived class to the base class. Given that these template could come in handy in many different circumstances, it might be worth the effort.

**Edit**: boost type traits actually has a [`copy_cv`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/copy_cv.html) template, so you could use that. There seems to be nothing to transfer the value type however.